# When coding a responsive design is it considered acceptable practice to have multiple markups for the same page elements?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am coding a responsive design which has several different navigation layouts based on screen resolution (p.s. I have no control over the design decisions where I work).

I am finding it very difficult to achieve the different layouts with just CSS changes alone. But I also don't like the idea of having duplicate markup for the same elements in numerous places as that seems ugly for reasons or maintenance and possible bad impact on SEO (although all but the default will be set to display none on page load).

Anyway What is the thought on this? Is it terribly against good practice to do this?

Comment: Not against best practices if you are using media-queries.

Comment: Media queries to display an accordion menu for example instead of a tabbed one is considered normal practice for responsive design. It's about giving the user the best experience, don't compromise this to suit your code.

Comment: Yes I am using media queries to adjust he CSS for different resolutions. What I want to know is regarding the markup. Is it ok to have multiple versions of the same html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is completely fine to do, make sure your keep your media queries at the bottom of you're CSS so those styles will be loaded last and In my opinion the smartest thing you can do is use a grid system with rows and columns and then say when you do your media query you can just display the width of all the columns and 100% which will stack every div you used and then yes for you navigation you'll need to rewrite some elements classes and ids for the media query but use a grid and make the column's width 100% on the mobile version.

Heres a grid simple grid system I build and you can see how I would do my navigation,

```
/* GRID */

*,*:before,*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.layout-row {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 96em;

    zoom: 1;
}
.layout-row .layout-row { width: auto;}

.layout-row:before, .layout-row:after {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    content: "\0020";    
}

.layout-row:after { clear: both;}

.layout-column {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding: 1em ;
}

.layout-column .layout-column { padding: 0;}


.one { width: 8.33333%;}

.two { width: 16.66667%;}

.three { width: 25%;}

.four { width: 33.33333%;}

.five { width: 41.66667%;}

.six { width: 50%;}

.seven { width: 58.33333%;}

.eight { width: 66.66667%;}

.nine { width: 75%;}

.ten { width: 83.33333%;}

.eleven { width: 91.66667%;}

.twelve { width: 100%;}

/* MODULES */

.layout-navigation { margin: -2em 0 0;}

.layout-navigation li {
    float: left;
    padding: 3em .75em .5em;
    text-align: center;
}

/* MOBILE MEDIA QUERY */

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {

.layout-row { width: 48em;}

.layout-column { width: 100%;}

.hide-mobile { display: none;}

.layout-navigation li {
    float: none;
    padding: 1em;
    background: #F3F3F3;
    text-align: left;
}
}
```